# Homological $\delta$-functors vs. topological homology theories

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, abelian-categories

While doing some reading on derived functors in homological algebra, I came across the concept of
homological $\delta$-functors. Just from exploring the definition, there are two questions (related to each other) which I can't seem to find good answers to:

(1) Most definitions I saw have [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80279/on-the-definition-of-delta-functors) form. Basically, a family $(T_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ of functors $T_n : \mathcal{A} \longrightarrow \mathcal{B}$ between abelian categories $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$, and for each short exact sequence
$$
  \mathsf{S} = (\, 0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0\,)
$$
in $\mathcal{A}$, a family $(\delta_n(\mathsf{S}))_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ of connection morphisms $\delta_n(\mathsf{S}) : T_nC \longrightarrow T_{n-1}A$ in $\mathcal{B}$. With these, each such s.e.s. $\mathsf{S}$ must give rise to a certain long exact sequence in $\mathcal{B}$.

However, it's the second condition that I'm more curious about: if $
  \mathsf{S}' = (\, 0 \to A' \to B' \to C' \to 0\,)
$ is some other s.e.s. in $\mathcal{A}$ and $f : \mathsf{S} \longrightarrow \mathsf{S}'$ is a morphism of s.e.s's, then the induced square
$$
  \begin{array}{ c c c c c }
    & T_nC & \overset{\delta_{n}(\mathsf{S})}\longrightarrow & T_{n-1}A \\
    \small{T_n(f_C)} & \downarrow & & \downarrow & \small{T_{n-1}(f_A)}\\
    & T_nC'& \overset{\delta_{n}(\mathsf{S'})}\longrightarrow & T_{n-1}A'
  \end{array}
$$
is required to commute. Now this looks like some kind of naturality square between the functors $T_n$ and $T_{n-1}$, except that of course the arguments don't match up (since $A$ and $C$ might be different). The definition given in the [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/delta-functor) does in fact mention that $\delta_n$ is a natural transformation. But natural in what? It seems to me like the right answer to this has to be that $\delta_n$ would be natural in the s.e.s's (after all, it has a ''component'' $\delta_n(\mathsf{S})$ for each s.e.s. $\mathsf{S}$), but then between which two functors is $\delta_n$ a natural transformation precisely?

(2) I suppose this is a less precise question, but perhaps also one of a bit more substance than (1). In algebraic topology, there is the (as I find, very elegant) notion of an abstract homology theory, a certain collection of functors satisfying the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms (found, for instance, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93Steenrod_axioms)). Seeing the definition of homological $\delta$-functors on abelian categories, I cannot help but notice that there is a striking resemblance. A homology theory too, is a family $(H_n)_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ of functors $H_n : \mathcal{T}\hspace{-3pt}op^2 \longrightarrow \mathcal{A}b$. Now $\mathcal{T}\hspace{-3pt}op^2$ is not an abelian category (at least as far as I know), so it wouldn't make sense to require that these functors be additive. However, the additivity of the functors seems to be replaced by the axiom of additivity (which says that if $X$ is a disjoint union of topological spaces $X_\alpha$, then $H_n(X)$ decomposes as the direct sum of the abelian groups $H_n(X_\alpha)$).

A homology theory too, subsumes a family $(\partial_n(X,A))_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ of connection morphisms (or rather ''boundary maps'') $\partial_n(X,A) : H_n(X,A) \longrightarrow H_{n-1}(A,\emptyset)$ in $\mathcal{A}b$. Just like in the $\delta$-functors case, an s.e.s. gave rise to a certain long exact sequence, in a homology theory, one has the axiom of exactness, which says that each topological pair $(X,A)$ in $\mathcal{T}\hspace{-3pt}op^2$ gives rise to a similar long exact sequence in homology. It looks like topological pairs $(X,A)$ play the role of s.e.s's $\mathsf{S}$ on the $\delta$-functors side.

Actually, in homology theories, $\partial_n$ is a natural transformation
$$
  \partial_n : H_n \Longrightarrow H_{n-1} \circ R
$$
where $R : \mathcal{T}\hspace{-3pt}op^2 \longrightarrow \mathcal{T}\hspace{-3pt}op^2$ is the restriction functor $(X,A) \mapsto (A,\emptyset)$. This is basically the reason why I'm asking question (1), which is that, for the sake of this analogy, it would be nice if there too the connection morphisms could be taken as the components of a natural transformation.

I guess excision and dimension just don't carry over to the $\delta$-functors side?

But even so, bearing in mind that on the $\delta$-functors side, one of the main examples really is given by the chain homology functors, I have to ask myself what underlying formal principle explains this analogy, i.e. if there is something like a more general theory which unifies both of these two theories.
I suspect it cannot just be that one is a ''special case'' of the other (or at least not when considered in their full generality - [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1750/can-anyone-give-me-a-good-example-of-two-interestingly-different-ordinary-cohomo) or [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1776/for-which-spaces-is-homology-or-cohomology-determined-by-the-eilenberg-steenro) discussion, if I'm understanding them correctly, seem to suggest that if one restricts topological (co)homology theories to reasonably nice spaces like CW-complexes, then essentially any homology theory factorizes through the chain homology functors,
for instance by taking the singular chain complex construction).

Comment: Good question. You are on the right track with (1). And I think you can easily work out the functors between which $\delta_n$ is a natural transformation. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

Martin Brandenburg's comment is quite accurate in how easy (1) is; now I'm sort of perplexed at not having seen the answer directly...

Anyways, for posterity, I guess this is how it goes: there are obvious functors
$$
  P_1, P_3 : \mathsf{SES}(\mathcal{A}) \longrightarrow \mathcal{A}
$$
from the category $\mathsf{SES}(\mathcal{A})$ of short exact sequences in $\mathcal{A}$,
mapping an short exact sequence $\mathsf{S} = (\, 0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0 \, )$ to $A$ and to $C$ respectively, and a map $f : \mathsf{S} \longrightarrow \mathsf{S}'$ to
its components $f_A$ and $f_C$, respectively. Then $\delta_n$ is a natural transformation
between the composites
$$
  \delta_n : T_n \circ P_3 \Longrightarrow T_{n-1} \circ P_1
$$
as functors from $\mathsf{SES}(\mathcal{A})$ to $\mathcal{B}$.

As for question (2), any input would still be highly appreciated.